miniset instalation error i: invoke-rc.d: initscript openvswitch-switch, action "start" failed
Overview
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2 and I need to install mininet program:
sudo apt install mininet

And the follow problem occurs:
pedro@DESKTOP-HNMS5UI:/mnt/c/Users/PedroFraga$ sudo apt install mininet
[sudo] password for pedro:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
mininet is already the newest version (2.3.0-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up openvswitch-switch (2.17.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
A dependency job for openvswitch-switch.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript openvswitch-switch, action "start" failed.
○ openvswitch-switch.service - Open vSwitch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvswitch-switch.service; enabled; vendor preset:
 enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 10 08:35:02 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Oct 10 08:35:02 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-swit
ch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 10 08:40:18 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Oct 10 08:40:18 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-swit
ch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 10 08:40:43 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Oct 10 08:40:43 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-swit
ch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 10 08:43:19 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Oct 10 08:43:19 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-swit
ch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 10 09:51:02 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Open vSwitch.
Oct 10 09:51:02 DESKTOP-HNMS5UI systemd[1]: openvswitch-switch.service: Job openvswitch-swit
ch.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dpkg: error processing package openvswitch-switch (--configure):
 installed openvswitch-switch package post-installation script subprocess returned error exi
t status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvswitch-switch
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

My WSL2 config
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
Linux DESKTOP-HNMS5UI 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
I try reinstall the program using:
sudo apt remove --purge openvswitch*

And install again
sudo apt install openvswitch-switch

